# Showing $(A\triangle B)\subseteq C$ iff $A\cup C=B\cup C$ (using logical equivalence only).

Tags: elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

*NB: This is an [alternative-proof](/questions/tagged/alternative-proof) question.*

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3614061/104041) to . . .

[Prove that $A \vartriangle B \subseteq C$ iff $A \cup C = B \cup C$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3614036/104041)

. . . I mentioned to the OP that I believe the result can be shown using "iff" statements all the way. In [the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614036/prove-that-a-vartriangle-b-subseteq-c-iff-a-cup-c-b-cup-c/3614061#comment7428559_3614061), I said I'd try that approach.

So far, I have

$$\begin{align}
A\triangle B\subseteq C&\iff (A\triangle B)\cup C=C\\
&\iff ((A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A))\cup C=C\\
&\iff (\{a\in A\mid a\notin B\}\cup\{b\in B\mid b\notin A\})\cup C=C\\
&\iff \{c\in C\mid \color{red}{(c\in A\land c\notin B)}\\
&\lor\color{blue}{(c\in B\land c\notin A)}\}=C\\
&\iff \{c\in C\mid (\color{red}{(c\in A\land c\notin B)}\lor \color{blue}{(c\in B)})\\
&\land (\color{red}{(c\in A\land c\notin B)}\lor \color{blue}{(c\notin A)})\}=C\\
&\iff \{c\in C\mid ((\color{red}{(c\in A)}\lor\color{blue}{(c\in B)})\\
&\land(\color{red}{(c\notin B)}\lor\color{blue}{(c\in B)}))\\
&\land((\color{red}{(c\in A)}\lor\color{blue}{(c\notin A)})\\
&\land(\color{red}{(c\notin B)}\lor\color{blue}{(c\notin A)}))\}=C\\
&\iff\{c\in C\mid (\color{red}{(c\in A)}\lor\color{blue}{(c\in B)})\\
&\land (\color{red}{(c\notin B)}\lor\color{blue}{(c\notin A)})\}=C\\
&\iff C\cup((A\cup B)\cap(A^c\cup B^c))=C,
\end{align}$$

but this leads me to $C\cup\varnothing =C$, which is vacuous.${}^\dagger$

So here's my question:

> How does one prove "$(A\triangle B)\subseteq C$ iff $A\cup C=B\cup C$" using only "iff" statements?

[This comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3614036/prove-that-a-vartriangle-b-subseteq-c-iff-a-cup-c-b-cup-c/3614061#comment7428699_3614036) delineates an approach but I'd prefer something that starts out as my attempt does.

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(A\cup B)\cap(A^\complement\cup B^\complement)$ contains anything that's in $A$ or $B$ but not both, so in general isn't $\emptyset$.

Comment: Ah, yes! Of course! It follows from de Morgan's Laws. Thank you, @J.G.